# How to acces usb otg (mass storage device) connected root folder to android phone and read data using android version > 7.0?

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

How to  acces  usb otg connected root folder to android phone and read data  using android version > 7.0?
Now I can read with version < 7.0.

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Thank you. **Thank you. But I'm looking for a way to access the root in the background without the user doing an action**